# maxevents parameter in epoll_wait() and the events array size

Tags: c, network-programming, epoll

In epoll usage, it is usually like the following:

```
struct epoll_event ev,events[20];
epfd=epoll_create(256);
。。。
nfds=epoll_wait(epfd,events,40,500);
```

Some articles are saying that the `maxevents` parameter in `epoll_wait` (namely the `40` in `epoll_wait(epfd,events,40,500);`) should not exceed the size parameter in `epoll_create`(namely the `256`).

I think the `maxevents` parameter should not exceed `20` in `ev, events[20]`, because events can only be registered to 20 events elements; otherwise, if there are 40 sockets which are active, then what will happen?

BTW, if I register more than 20 sockets and there are more than 20 active events(sockets), but the events array `events[20]` has only 20 events, what will happen?

Answer (score 4):

At any single call of `epoll_wait` you'll at most receive as many events as you have room for, but of course events don't get lost if there are more than that queued up -- you'll simply get them at a later call. Since you'll be calling `epoll_wait` in a loop anyway, that shouldn't be an issue at all.

The one interesting consideration I can think of is when you have multiple threads read from the same epoll-fd concurrently. In that case the size of your event array determines how many events get handled by a single thread (i.e. a smaller number might give you greater parallelism).

Comment: even for EPOLLET events, they can still be gotten in the later call? how can many threads use the same epoll-fd, no mutex is needed?

Comment: @misteryes: ET/LT has nothing to do with the size of the array. ET/LT determines when an event occurs. `epoll_wait` will always, eventually, report all the events that have occurred, just in small chunks at a time.

Comment: @misteryes: Reading from an epoll-fd is threadsafe as long as the events are all "one-shot". Then they're guaranteed to be polled in precisely one thread.

Comment: what do you mean by "one-shot"?

Comment: @misteryes: I mean using the `EPOLLONESHOT` flag. The point is that a one-shotted event is "disarmed" after it's been fired, so the processing thread is guaranteed to be the only one handling it. It's up to the processing thread to "rearm" the event when it's done.

Comment: I still don't understand why it is threadsafe with a EPOLLONESHOT flag set, and it is not threadsafe without EPOLLONESHOT set. If the processing thread re-register it to epfd, it is the same as non-one-shot events.