# Do I need to re-initialize epoll_wait's events array?

Tags: c, epoll

1) I have `epoll_wait(..., events, ...)` loop, do I need to reinitialize the events array before each iteration?

2) According to `epoll()` manual examples there is no need, is it a mistake?

3) Does fds that I didn't handle yet will be re-written in the array next iteration? (I'm using level triggered epoll) I won't miss ready fds?

I have tried reading the kernel code to check if it overwrites the array each iteration or only adds to it, but with no success (if you can show me it will be great).

```
struct epoll_event ev, events[MAX_EVENTS];
...
for (;;) {
    nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`epoll_wait` returns you the number of `events`' elements it has written and you shouldn't care about the rest of the array. So I would say - no, you don't need to reinitialize this array or even initialize it as long as you always use the first `nfds` elements.

To elaborate further: after each call to `epoll_wait` you know for sure that it filled the first `nfds` elements of the `events` array, so you'll have to iterate through these elements to check what events occurred at which descriptors. However the rest of the elements in the `events` array are basically garbage either from the previous `epoll_wait` calls or from whatever memory region this array is allocated at, so all the elements with index >= `nfds` don't contain any useful data.

Comment: Can you elaborate about "as long as you always use the first nfds elements."

Comment: @IdolAdmin, I've extended the answer.

Comment: I understand, Thanks!!!

Adding to the question:
What happens if i allocate smaller array then the ready fds, would they be re-written on next iteration as i didn't handled them? or would they be lost?

Comment: @IdolAdmin, that's a very good question but unfortunately I have no idea, neither I could find any documentation on the matter. I think you'll have to experiment a bit to find out. I would also suggest asking this as separate question because it could be very useful for others.

Comment: i found this answer, which claims that the events would show up next iteration, i would need to verify this..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640430/maxevents-parameter-in-epoll-wait-and-the-events-array-size